# Create solr_core for search_api_solr 4.x with docker solr 8

Tags: 9, search, virtual-machine

I used to create my solr instance for drupal like this:

```
docker run -v $PWD/solrconf:/asdentcore  -e SOLR_JAVA_MEM="-Xms2G -Xmx2G" --restart unless-stopped  -p 8984:8983 -t --name asdentDevSolr -d solr:8.11
docker exec -it --user=solr asdentDevSolr  bin/solr create_core -c asdentcore -d /asdentcore
```

Where ./solrconf contains the files from modules/contrib/search_api_solr/solr-conf-templates/7.x.

With the new 4.x branch of search_api_solr (and 8.x contents) I get

```
ERROR: Error CREATEing SolrCore 'asdentcore': Unable to create core [asdentcore] Caused by: solr.ICUCollationField
```

I've already tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53161034/solr-error-unable-to-create-core-mycore-caused-by-solr-icucollationfield - didn't help.

Container logs shows the following errors:

```
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Unable to create core [asdentcore]
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not load conf for core asdentcore: Can't load schema /var/solr/data/asdentcore/conf/schema.xml: Plugin init failure for [schema.xml] fieldType "collated_de": Error loading class 'solr.ICUCollationField'
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Can't load schema /var/solr/data/asdentcore/conf/schema.xml: Plugin init failure for [schema.xml] fieldType "collated_de": Error loading class 'solr.ICUCollationField'
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Plugin init failure for [schema.xml] fieldType "collated_de": Error loading class 'solr.ICUCollationField'
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error loading class 'solr.ICUCollationField'
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: solr.ICUCollationField
```

Comment: Never had an issue like this. Can you actually verify the container directory is mounted and accessible to the container user at that location?

Comment: Yes, I did, it's accessible. I'll add the java errors to my question.

Comment: Also, if I set up the solr as usual with the 7.x templates till it works, then bash into the container and copy over the new conf/* files downloaded via search-api UI to /var/solr/data/asdentcore/conf - the server breaks with java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: solr.ICUCollationField - bah that's sooo bad...

Comment: Is that container missing those files?

Comment: Which one? Yes, the classes I'd suppose.

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api_solr/issues/3181819#comment-13899895

Answer (score 1):

Kudos to Kevin. The solution is

here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62652640/error-when-initializing-solr-core-error-loading-class-solr-icucollationfield

and here https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api_solr/issues/3181819#comment-13899895

I had to replace in the downloaded `solrcore.properties` the line `solr.install.dir=../../..` with `solr.install.dir=/opt/solr`.

One day of my live ...